# How does ODBC pull database connection details?

Tags: macros, odbc, sybase

I currently have a Macro which is connecting to a sybase database using ODBC. It's making the connection by running the following:

Set conX = wrkODBC.OpenConnection("Connection1", , True, strConn)

where strConn = "ODBC;DSN=Server_Name;APP=Daily Task;DB=db_name;UID=uname;PWD=pwd;"

The problem I am having is that this connection is working for some Server_Name's but not others. When it doesn't work I get a  Error "3146 - ODBC--call failed".

What I don't understand is where it is pulling the server details from. So for example, when using embarcadero rapid to connect to a sybase database, it will use the sql.ini file to pull the server connection details based on the server_name.

I have checked and all the Sybase Servers I am testing are in the sql.ini file and my env variables are pointing to the correct sybase version. I've checked ODBC and it is only picking up a SQL Server driver.

Can anyone please explain how ODBC pulls the server name connection details? I don't understand why it works for some server names, but not others (FYI, I have tested the uname and pwd is rapid to make sure it is correct).

Any information would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue was that I was looking at my odbc connections under control panel. I should mention that I am on windows 7. What I had to do was update my ODBC connection details here:

C:/Windows/SYSWOW64/odbcad32.exe
--This is for 32bit!

This had some connections set up which is why I could connect to some servers but not all of them.